# How to stop a while loop in c++

Tags: c++, while-loop

"Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them.
Exit the program when a terminating '|' is entered."

my attempt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;



int main(){

    int firstnumber;
    int secondnumber;
    int stopnumber;


    while(stopnumber!='|'){

        cout <<"Please enter an integer, followed by another integer: \n";
        cin >> firstnumber >> secondnumber;
        cout <<"\n" <<  firstnumber <<"   "<<  secondnumber<< "    \n";

    }

return 0;
}
```

the program takes 2 number and prints them, but when i enter '|' , it goes in infinite loop. How to stop the program when i enter '|'

Thanks

Comment: You never change `stopnumber`. What did you expect?

Comment: It would be necessary to initialise `stopnumber` to something other than `'|'` to prevent undefined behaviour on the first loop iteration.  Then assigning `stopnumber = '|'` within the loop will stop the loop when execution reaches the `}`.   Your code is doing neither.

Comment: Do I even need stopnumber? as someone else suggested I could just use firstnumber and secondnumber as my conditions in the while loop

Comment: The problem with the input is that you can enter anything. What happens if you enter letters?

Comment: Thanks ZDF, so I need to sanitise my inputs somehow!?

Comment: No, you don't need `stopnumber` if you test for some condition involving other variables or constants.

Comment: @Ross_Barkley Read about `istream::get`, `::isdigit` & `istream::putback`.

Comment: I have been reading through the book ZDF and haven't come across that yet. I assume to do this task, I shouldn't have to use things that haven't been taught yet?

Peter, I have tried 
while(firstnumber!='|' && secondnumber!='|'){ 
but it didnt work

Comment: `'|'` is not a number. So trying to read it as a number will fail.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your loop should look like:

1. Read a character (`std::cin::get`).
2. If successful and your character is the stop symbol, break the loop.
3. If your character is not a digit (`::isdigit`), continue looping.
4. If your character is a digit, put it back(`std::cin::putback`).
5. Read two integers.
6. If successful, display them, if not, clear the stream (`std::cin::clear`).

You will have to patiently try to understand what `get`, `putback` & `isdigit` are doing.

**[EDIT]**
[Run it](http://ideone.com/iDJ5Ct)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
  char c;
  while ( std::cin.get( c ) && c != '|' )
  {
    if ( !std::isdigit( c ) )
      continue;

    std::cin.putback( c );

    int i, j;
    if ( std::cin >> i >> j )
      std::cout << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;
    else
      std::cin.clear();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: streams support a `.peek()` member, which can help avoid the read/check/put-back cycle.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The character must be removed from stream.

Comment: Eventually, perhaps--but if it's a digit, you don't want to remove it right then. And in this case, the apparent intent is that if it's a `|`, the program will immediately exit, in which case it doesn't matter whether you remove it from the stream or not.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I don't see how `peek` simplifies the code - I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is testing `stopnumber` which is never set.  If you set `stopnumber` to either `firstnumber` or `secondnumber` then perhaps you can get your logic to work but there is a step missing as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you need to exit directly after you receive the '|' character or whether you mind running through the rest of the loop first before exiting it......

Personally I'd want to exit straight after receiving the '|' so would follow the basic idea of....

```
int a,b;

while(){
  read your values a,b in
  if (a='|' || b='|'){exit()};
  print your values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have found my answer

I tried putting my cin in the while loop as such

```
int firstnumber;
int secondnumber;

  while (cin >> firstnumber >> secondnumber)
```

And it worked! Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: Any non-digit character will break the loop, not only `'|'`.

Comment: You will have first to decide what you'll do with invalid input. You have two choices: 1. Display an error message and exit the program (simpler). 2. Ignore the invalid input (harder).

Answer (score 0):

std::stoi(std::string) - returns int from std::string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isNumber(std::string &str) {
    for (auto i : str) {
        if (i < '0' || i > '9') return false;
    return true;
}

int main () {
    int a, b;
    std::string s;

    while (true) {
        std::cin >> s;
        if (s == "|" || !isNumber(s)) break;
        a = std::stoi(s);

        std::cin >> s;
        if (s == "|" || !isNumber(s)) break;
        b = std::stoi(s);

        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if you enter `abc 123`?

Comment: @ZDF Why would you like to enter abc 123? Ross_Barkley asked to make app that reads 2 integers or ends when '|' is written.

Comment: A user types anything she/he likes. What happens if you enter `||`?

Comment: 1. The new code will break the loop for any non-digit character (_"Exit the program when a terminating '|' is entered"_). 2. `stoi` will throw if it is not able to convert `s`, so there is no need for `isNumber`.